# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-answers

I just saw that an answer I posted yesterday was downvoted and deleted:

[image]

As I cannot conceive how any of the [reasons for deleting listed in the help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) apply, could anyone clarify?

- It is obviously not a comment
- It is obviously not a question
- I'm not thanking anyone for anything there, nor saying I have / had the same / a related problem
- There's no other answer I duplicated. The only other answer on the question came more than one hour later.
- It does not contain any link, so cannot be a link-only answer
- It is certainly more than a partial answer

Also, I'm a bit shocked I got 4 downvotes and no upvotes there, especially as the upvoted answer has worse pseudo-assembler-code.

Comment: Bare in mind I have no idea if what you posted is correct or not, all I can think is it is an incorrect answer, but I think people who thought it was an incorrect answer should have commented telling you what why they think it is incorrect rather than just downvoting.

Comment: Shouldn't have been deleted, but I don't have the rep to cast an undelete vote.  Good luck.

Comment: Myeah, that should not have been deleted.

Comment: I agree with @LanceRoberts, and I've undeleted it.

Comment: I also agree with @Bart, but I don't like to inflate his ego by saying so. Errr... oops...

Comment: Elsewhere I was asking why some perfectly good questions or answers got rapidly downvoted and deleted and it was suggested that often this occurs when someone takes note (and offense) of the question/answer and gripes about it in a chat room with his buddies.  They then pile on.  I find this behavior offensive and contrary to SO principles, but there's little that can be done about it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I just found one of my answers being deleted by you in spite of that being a one of the legit answers to that question. What should I do ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I believe the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23897438/1) tells most of the story.

You started your answer with a quote of part of the question. But **did not format it** as a blockquote.

People most probably saw this as you asking a question or copying it.

The first edit fixed that - but it was **long** after most downvotes and delete votes came.

Lesson learned: formatting is important.

Comment: Oh yes, good point. I'd looked at the revision history and didn't notice it hadn't been formatted as a quote in the first.

Comment: By now I should have learned to completely shun the question-mark in answers, unless I triple-checked proper quoting... thanks.

Comment: hehe, @Deduplicator Particularly in the first sentence, yes. Unfortunately, some people really do sort of shoot from the hip on those. I should troll Oded and edit the first sentence of this answer into a question... "Do you think the first revision tells the story?" Hmmm... that could come across as a bit rude...

Comment: One might say that's symptomatic of a poor review process. Reading beyond the first sentence is *vital* if you want to be a reviewer.

Comment: Robos are back.  Err.. they were never gone.

Answer (score 16):

I noticed this answer while looking for posts to delete. I realized that it was getting downvotes and delete votes because it looked like a question and not an answer - because of the lack of a blockquote.

So I edited it and refrained from deleting it.

Comment: Saw you giving me a hand there with the quoting, thanks.

Comment: wowwwwwww You have done a great work. Lol